# HttpWebRequest "operation has timed out"

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest, download

I am using an httpWebRequest in my windows app to download files from a webserver (sURL), to a local folder (fileDestination) as such:

```
Public Function DownloadFile(ByVal sURL As String, _
                        ByVal fileDestination As String, _
                        ByVal WebRequestType As String) As Boolean  


    Dim URLReq As HttpWebRequest
        Dim URLRes As HttpWebResponse
        Dim FileStreamer As FileStream
        Dim bBuffer(999) As Byte
        Dim iBytesRead As Integer
        Dim folderDestination As String
        Dim sChunks As Stream

        Try

            FileStreamer = New FileStream(fileDestination, FileMode.Create)

            URLReq = WebRequest.Create(sURL)
            URLRes = URLReq.GetResponse 'Error occurs here!!
            sChunks = URLReq.GetResponse.GetResponseStream
            DownloadProgressBar.Value = 0
            DownloadProgressBar.Maximum = URLRes.ContentLength

            Do
                iBytesRead = sChunks.Read(bBuffer, 0, 1000)
                FileStreamer.Write(bBuffer, 0, iBytesRead)
            Loop Until iBytesRead = 0

            sChunks.Close()
            FileStreamer.Close()
            URLRes.Close()

            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try

End Function
```

This works fine for the first few files. But then it starts giving the following error on the `URLReq.GetResponse` line:

> "operation has timed out"

Anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: How big are the files it's downloading when it crashes?

Comment: I noticed you tagged the question as asp.net, is this all occurring in an asp.net web page or is this a windows app that is request from an asp.net website?

Comment: @Urbycoz, just to ask the obvious, are you able to download whatever you're trying to access using a regular web browser just fine? Also, is whatever you are trying to download from a server that you control or from a third-party? If the latter, some sites (Google in particular) inspect the user agent header looking for bots. Try manually setting the request's user agent to some common user agent.

Comment: @Chris. Yes, I can download all of the files directly from a browser. Whatsmore it is not any one particular file that always fails. If I do them in a different order, it fails on different files. No, not downloading from third party- it's our own server.

Comment: @OneShot. Oops, just realised my mistake. It's actually a windows app downloaded using clickOnce technology. No "asp.net" involved. I've removed the tag. +1 for pointing that out.

Comment: You're not by any chance targeting the 1.1 framework, are you?

Comment: @Chris. Er, yeeeeees.....(suspiciously)

Comment: @Urbycoz, Check this post out, he says he needed to add a `Request.Abort` call. http://www.andrewdothay.net/blog/2007/07/25/SystemNetWebExceptionTheOperationHasTimedout.aspx

Comment: mmm...Looks like I may have too many requests running at once. Seems 4 is the maximum.

Comment: @Urbycoz, If that's the case you might be able to set `System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`

Comment: @Chris. You are dead right! Thank you. I set System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit=10, and it fixed the problem. It was actually set to 2 originally. If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Urbycoz, I turned it into an answer, glad it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're targeting the 1.1 framework and are running multiple concurrent requests try setting `System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`

Answer (score 1):

The timeout is set to 10000 milliseconds (or 10 seconds). Is that long enough for the roundtrip to the web server?

The [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout.aspx) says the default is 100 seconds (100000 ms) is there any reason you changed that default?

Comment: Yes. It was taking forever to bomb out every time, and I got sick of waiting. I'll take it back out again. Problem still occurs.